# Cardinality of set of order-preserving maps of paths with ordering defined by a set.

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, combinatorial-proofs

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. For every subset $S\subseteq \left[ n-1\right]$ we define a poset $P_S=\left([n],\le_{P_S}\right)$ given by the covering relation $\lessdot$ which is defined as
\begin{align*} 
 &\forall i\in S
 & i+1&\lessdot i \\
 &\forall i\in\left[n-1\right]\setminus S
 & i&\lessdot i+1\\
\end{align*}
Clearly, the [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of these kind of orderings represents a path with an ordering defined by the corresponding set. For instance if  $n=3$ we have the posets
[image]

### **Useful Definitions**

- A function $f\colon P_S\to [m]$ is called *order-preserving* for $P_S$, if for any $x,y\in P_S$ $$x<_{P_S}y\implies f(x)\le f(y),$$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}$.
- We denote with $\Omega(P_S,m)$ the *order polynomial* of $P_S$ for $m$, i.e.
  $$\Omega(P_S,m)=\#\left\{ f\colon P_S\to [m]\,\mid  f\;\; \text{is order-preserving}\right\}$$
- We call an order-preserving bijection $\omega\colon P_S\to[n]$ *natural labeling* of $P_S$.
- For any permutation $w\in\mathcal{S}_n$ we denote with $\mathsf{Des}(w)$ the *descent set* of $w$, i.e.
  $$\mathsf{Des}(w)=\left\{ i\in\left[n\right]\mid w\left(i\right)>w\left(i+1\right)\right\} $$
- We denote with $A_S$  the set of permutations that corresponds to the natural labelings of $P_S$, i.e. $$A_{S}=\left\{ w\in\mathcal{S}_{n}\mid w=\left(\omega\left(1\right),\omega\left(2\right),\dots,\omega\left(n\right)\right)\text{ for some natural labeling }\omega\text{ of }P_{S}\right\} $$

---

### **The question**

We want to calculate, for any given $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ the sum of the order polynomials on the subsets $S\subseteq[n-1]$, i.e. $$\sum_{S\subseteq[n-1]}\Omega\left(P_{S},m\right).$$

---

### **My progress**

It seems that the requested sum is equal to

> $$m(1+m)^{n-1},$$

but I did not manage to show it.

---

It is not hard to show that the set of all the natural labelings for a given subset $S$ has the same cardinality as the set of all permutations of $[n]$ with descent set equal to $S$, i.e.
$$\#A_S=\#\left\{ \omega\colon P_{S}\to[n]\mid\omega\;\text{natural labeling}\right\} =\#\left\{ w\in\mathcal{S}_{n}\mid\mathsf{Des}\left(w\right)=S\right\} .$$

It is well known that $$\Omega\left(P_{S},m\right)=\sum_{w\in A_{S}}\binom{m+n-\mathsf{des}\left(w\right)-1}{n}.$$

I tried to use these facts in order to calculate the requested sum but I failed...

Comment: How you prove that all the natural labelings for a given subset S has the cardinality of all permutations of [n] with descent set equal to S??

Answer (score 1):

Summing the order polynomials is the same as counting the number of pairs $(S, f) ∈ \mathcal P([n - 1]) \times ([n] → [m])$ such that $f$ is order-preserving on $P_s$. There are $m$ choices for $f(1)$. Then for each $i = 2, \dotsc, n$, either

- $f(i) < f(i - 1)$ and $i - 1 ∈ S$, or
- $f(i) > f(i - 1)$ and $i - 1 ∉ S$, or
- $f(i) = f(i - 1)$ and either $i - 1 ∈ S$ or $i - 1 ∉ S$,

giving us $m + 1$ joint choices for $f(i)$ and whether $i - 1 ∈ S$. A unique pair $(S, f)$ is determined by each sequence of choices, of which there are $m(m + 1)^{n - 1}$.

Comment: (+1) This is correct but very terse. To expand a little, if we choose to put $i-1$ in $S$, then we must have $1\le f(i)\le f(i-1)$, so there are $f(i-1)$ possibilities; otherwise we must have $f(i-1)\le f(i)\le m$, and there are $m-f(i-1)+1$ possibilities. The total number of possible choices for $\langle 1_S(i-1),f(i)\rangle$ is therefore $m+1$, where $1_S$ is the indicator function of $S$. Choosing $f(1)$ and $\langle 1_S(i-1),f(i)\rangle$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$ can of course be done in $m(m+1)^{n-1}$ ways and uniquely determines one of the desired pairs $\langle S,f\rangle$.